# how to get date and time in zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework

in PHP Code

```
$timestamp=Date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I want to get server time in zend controller
am using `Zend_Date()` but am getting error like that 
Zend_Date'  class not found

please help me any one.

Comment: Try to follow solution mentioned in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075518/zend-date-is-giving-me-fatal-error-msg

Comment: Hi. I am getting output for the same line. Please check whether the ZendDebug is enabled or not.

Comment: in my zend library am not able to find Zend/date.php
where i want to find?

Answer (score 0):

You can see this error because you use Zend Autoloader incorrectly.

Please read this [Basic Autoloader Usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/learning.autoloading.usage.html).

After you solve autoload problem you can use Zend_Date:

```
$date = new Zend_Date();
print $date->get();
```

Comment: is there any other link for basic autoloader usage? am not able to understand this document. then i can't able find zend/date 
in my library
where i want to find?

Comment: Before you will able to use some class in php you have to include it in your document .php. So you can use require or include methods

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing it from within another namespace you may need to specify the top level namespace try changing 
`$date = new Zend_Date();` to `$date = new \Zend_Date();`

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$d = new Zend_Date();
echo 'Your date is: ' . $d->get();
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

i did so many research finally i found zend framework2 not having zend_Date class inbuilt-in,
So now am using this solution

```
$this->date = new DateTime();
$this->timestamp = $this->date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Might be helpful to someone.